# How to publish my Rest Web service over IIS (Some thing wrong with my Web.Config file)

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, iis, restful-url

I have 3 projects in my RESTService.Lib
They are as follows (this image also contains my xml):
[image: Visual Studio]

My RESTDemoServices.cs contains this code which works fine:

```
namespace RESTService.Lib
{
    [ServiceContract(Name = "RESTDemoServices")]
    public interface IRESTDemoServices
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Client/{id}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        string GetClientNameById(string Id);
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class RestDemoServices:IRESTDemoServices
    {
        public string GetClientNameById(string Id)
        {
            return ("Le nom de client est Jack et id est : " +Id );
        }
    }
}
```

And Program.cs in RESTService.Host contains code which is:

```
namespace RESTService.Host
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RestDemoServices DemoServices = new RestDemoServices();
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
            WebHttpBehavior behavior = new WebHttpBehavior();

            WebServiceHost _serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(DemoServices, new Uri("http://localhost:8000/DEMOService/"));
            _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRESTDemoServices), binding, "");
            _serviceHost.Open();
            Console.ReadKey();
            _serviceHost.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And Web.Config contains the code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="svcBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
      <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
          <binding>
            <security mode="Transport"/>
          </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <services>
        <service name="RestService.WebHost" behaviorConfiguration="svcBehavior">
          <endpoint  name="" binding="WebHttpBinding" address="soap" contract="RESTDemoServices.IRESTDemoServices" />
        </service>
      </services>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Why am I not able to get it to publish on IIS?
The code works fine when I create a client and consume it.  Perhaps the problem is in Web.Config, but could someone please point out what is the problem there?

The error is:

> 403.14 - The web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

[image: Error screen]

Comment: Isn't it accessible when you access it using `?wsdl` at the end of the URL?

Comment: @Kamo , Sorry i couldn't understand what u said , I am doing it first time. But it works fine when i pass an Id (for example "22") in my client code and consumes this webservice code. It also works when i open browser after running VStudio code and write this link http://localhost:8000/DEMOService/Client/25  but when i try to publish it on IIS it do not work with the error id that i mentioned in link at last of my question. I am sure there is something wrong in my Web.Config but what ..That i am not able to find.

Comment: Ah sorry, it is REST webservice. Have you tried accessing published WS with /DEMOService/Client/25 url?

Comment: @Kamo yes i already told you here http://prntscr.com/8dwny9 . Can you please see my Web.Config if everything right there (according to REST service configuration) specially the <endpoint  ...> part

Comment: @Kamo How should i change my code to publish it with /DEMOService/Client/25 url?

Comment: Can you check whether WS is accessible using `address="soap"` because this attribute indicates WS URL??

Comment: Please come on chatting .. i am waiting u there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89037/discussion-between-kamo-and-xav-xav).